# Why is the Google Batch Drive API unreliable?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have some code that creates a `multipart/mixed` POST request of `https://www.googleapis.com/batch/drive/v3` ([doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/performance#batch-requests)), however, I've noticed that some percentage of the time I get the following response from the server:

```
[{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Failed to parse batch request, error: Failed in parsing HTTP headers: (125 bytes redacted). Received batch body: (0) bytes redacted",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Failed to parse batch request, error: Failed in parsing HTTP headers: (125 bytes redacted). Received batch body: (0) bytes redacted",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "bad request"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
]
```

I've implemented a retry with an exponential backoff strategy. With a retry count of 10, I can reliably get a successful response, but what I can't figure out is anything about the failed requests that are wrong.  I've debugged the individual requests, and they all work. If I call the APIs directly and not as part of a batched request, the success rate is so far perfect. However, putting them into a batch request results in a failure rate of around 60%. Also, with the retry strategy, I can not see any difference between the "invalid" requests and the "valid" requests. They are character-for-character identical.  Does anyone have any ideas on what I can debug to track this down?

Comment: batching is more trouble than its worth

Comment: Unfortunate but probably helpful advice. I have a separate implementation that just uses direct API calls and it takes about 3 times as long. Even more confusing to me is that batching seems more reliable for the export API the "list files" API seems to have the most trouble.

Comment: While at Google (I used to work on the Gmail Ads team) a lot of these rough edges were hidden by the gRPC libraries and clients that we had access to.

Comment: I would like to understand your current issue. Can I ask you about the detail of `Even more confusing to me is that batching seems more reliable for the export API the "list files" API seems to have the most trouble.`?

Comment: I have a generic compose batch API request function that can take and array of folder file list requests and and document export requests. My use case is to first grab a list of root level files and folders. The folders are then converted into a batch of folder list requests now with a `'[folder id]' in parents` added to the query. So far I have found that an array of 70 sub folder requests in a batch fails about 60% of the time but a batch of 70 document export requests only fails about 5% of the time. And retrying always eventually works. I can put more data in a gist if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, in 1st batch request, the file and folder list are retrieved. As 2nd batch request, the Google Document files are exported from the 1st folder, and also the file and subfolder list in the 1st folder are retrieved. As 3rd batch request, the Google Document files are exported from the subfolders under the 1st folder, and also the file and subfolder list in each subfolder are retrieved. And, this cycle is run as 4th and 5th, and more. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Jason Sperske By the way, when you reply comment, when you add `@` to the username like `@username`, the user can notice your reply.

Comment: @Tanaike, exactly correct. In the initial request the parent is null (root level) and the response gives me a list of files, folders and a nextPageToken for the rest of the root results. The files are collected and the folders and nextToken are turned into new requests that are gathered into a batch. I've tried isolating each type, I've tried limiting batch and page size. I've even copied a failed request as a curl command and just run it 2 or 3 times. Same command, same headers takes a few chances to succeed.

Comment: @Jason Sperske Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that you are using batch requests in every folder for retrieving the file and folder list. For example, how about the following flow? 1. Retrieve all files and folders as a list. 2. Export the files using the list with the batch request? But, I'm not sure whether this is included in your expected direction. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Jason Sperske By the way, now, when I tested retrieving the file and folder list using ["Method: files.list"](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/list) with the batch requests (100 requests per 1 request), it occurred with no errors. But, I would like to replicate your situation, when I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of a solution. I apologize that I cannot correctly replicate your situation, soon.

Comment: @Tanaike, I created a more robust measurement setup, and I think the success with batch exporting that I was seeing was an early fluke.  It appears when I make a single batch request, I see more successes than failures, but the follow-up request (sent imminently after the initial request is processed) are more of a shot in the dark. To measure the success rate I took 9 samples of the file list batches (60.83% success) and 9 samples of the document export batches (52.83%). If there was some extra header I could pass to get more helpful errors, or a request linter even.

Comment: @Jason Sperske Thank you for replying. From your reply, I would like to try to correctly replicate your issue of `Failed to parse batch request, error: Failed in parsing HTTP headers: (125 bytes redacted). Received batch body: (0) bytes redacted` using "Method: files.list". When I could correctly replicate it, I would like to think of the reason for it and a solution or a workaround. I deeply apologize that I cannot correctly replicate your situation soon.